# Modeling Churn (supervised vs. unsupervised)

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

would appreciate your feedback/comments.

I am attempting to predict churn for my business. I am dealing with relatively few churns and a timespan of 1 year. A customer who has not churned today may churn tomorrow which seems like it poses a problem when treating this as a supervised learning problem.

I attempt to solve this problem in the following fashion (bootstrapping):

- loop 50 times
- for every loop, divide data into training/test (80%/20%) and get churn probabilities for test set using logistic reg built from training
- average churn probabilities for test observations to determine overall churn probability for each observation
- I also capture std deviation of these probabilities

After this, I can isolate non-churned customers and get a probability of churn for each of them. I treat false positive (predicted to churn but did not actually churn) as customers likely to churn.

When I try running a Random Forest & Boosting in a similar fashion, the model predicts churns with a very high accuracy, and none of the non-churned customers have churn probabilities greater than 10% (false positive extremely low). which is very different from what I get with logistic regression. Why is that?

Does this seem like a sound approach? Would appreciate any feedback I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Your general approach is good - but mind the time variable. Let's say you have 12 months of data. You'll have to create snapshots of your data, and create new train/test populations for each run.
For example, for the first run, you use the KPIs that you collect based on month 1. Ensure that you are using the data of only the active customers on month 1. Next define the target variable as clients that churned at month 2. Build a model. Use this model, but this time - use it on the data collected based on month 2, and try to predict which customer will churn on month 3.
Now you can combine Month 1 Data + Month 2 Target with Month 2 Data + Month 3 Target, and move to predict month 4 - and so forth.
The time element is crucial for predicting churn.